# Layer Preview not working over HTTPS

Tags: geoserver

I'm running Geoserver over **`HTTPS`** and when I preview a layer with `openlayers3` format the page throws an error.

The error point that some resources

`i.e. http://mydomain.com/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js`

are blocked because are requested over `HTTP`.

[image]

---

I tried to change it manually but I can't find the file.

Is there some configuration file I need to change so that the page request the content over HTTPS?

Comment: Are you saying you are using OpenLayers as an output format from a GeoServer service, or have an OpenLayers client already, and are trying to consume an HTTPS service from GeoServer?

Comment: Sorry if It was unclear. Is the own Geoserver's LayerPreview Page (selecting openlayers from the dropdown output format) which request those resources over HTTP. Using WMS or other services in my own openlayers client works great. It's just the LayerPreview Page.

Comment: what if you use https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js for a test?

Comment: @Mapperz The problem is not about openlayers. I added an image to show you what I mean.

Comment: Layer preview is really only designed to work from localhost. Feel free to open a PR with a fix though

Comment: @IanTurton The Geoserver team should really fix this! The protocol part of the request url should not default to http but rather use whatever protocol the preview page is accessed on.

Comment: as I said feel free to open a PR with a fix.

Comment: Seems that in my case it may be because HAProxy is converting the https request into an http request. Not sure why Geoserver is using the https host name but http scheme though. I have opened an issue here: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8952

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `Proxy Base URL` in global settings worked for me.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/globalsettings.html

In your example, the `Proxy Base URL` you should enter is:

```
https://mydomain.com/geoserver/
```